# Spark sum up values regardless of keys

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My list of tuples looks like this:

```
Tup = [(u'X45', 2), (u'W80', 1), (u'F03', 2), (u'X61', 2)]
```

I want to sum all values up, in this case, `2+1+2+2=7`

I can use `Tup.reduceByKey()` in spark if keys are the same. But which function can I use in spark to sum all values up regardless the key?

I've tried `Tup.sum()` but it give me `(u'X45', 2, u'W80', 1, u'F03', 2, u'X61', 2)`

BTW Due to large dataset, I want to sum it up in RDD, so I don't use `Tup.collect()` and `sum` it up out of Spark.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is pretty easy.

Conceptually, you should first map on your original RDD and extract the 2nd value. and then sum those

In Scala

```
val x = List(("X45", 2), ("W80", 1), ("F03", 2), ("X61", 2))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(x)
rdd.map(_._2).sum()
```

In Python

```
x = [(u'X45', 2), (u'W80', 1), (u'F03', 2), (u'X61', 2)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(x)
y = rdd.map(lambda x : x[1]).sum()
```

in both cases the sum of 7 is printed.

Comment: No need for lambda here. Just call `values()`.

Comment: @zero323 u mean x.values()? cuz when i use it, it said "tuple object has no function values()", thanks

Comment: thanks guys, i hope i can thumb up both of u but got insufficient reputation.